# Selective replication in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, replication

I wanted to replicate my database across 2 servers both using sql server 2005. The problem is that the main server have both 'User' and 'Admin' data in a table. At the other end , I want to replicate the entire database but the 'Admin' data should not be replicated.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? Either by configuring the replication or by manual tweaks.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk through the replication setup wizard.  After you select the tables you want to publish, there is an entire screen dedicated to filtering your data.

[image]

Click Add, then pick your table and supply the WHERE clause

[image]

Comment: Thanks KenJ I think this ought to solve the issue.  Just one more question can I also give Delete,Insert,Update command along with the select command in filter statement ?